# No Class Def Found Error with Google Android Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

KEYWhen I run a new activity with an Intent to launch google map V2, I have this error :

```
05-29 17:54:04.389: E/AndroidRuntime(26353): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.monprojet.Geolocalisation
```

Before this error in the LogCat I read this error :

```
05-29 17:54:01.319: E/dalvikvm(26353): Could not find class 'com.monprojet.Geolocalisation', referenced from method criquebeuf.Accueil$1.onItemClick
```

I have in my Manifest the Activity " Geolocalisation ".

But the thing very strange, It's that in an another Project with the same code without all other activity of my real application, my activity " Geolocalisation " run !!

I don't understand why ?

**My Manifest how doesn't work:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exemple.cbn"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.exemple.cbn.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.exemple.cbn.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Permissions pour la geolocalisation. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="KEY"/>


   <!-- Permissions pour la geolocalisation.-->
    <activity
        android:name="criquebeuf.Accueil"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 


    <activity
       android:name="criquebeuf.Geolocalisation" 
       android:label="@string/titre_geolocalisation" >
    </activity>


    <activity
       android:name="com.monprojet.Carrieres" 
       android:label="@string/titre_Carrieres" >
    </activity>

     <activity
       android:name="com.monprojet.InfosPresentation" 
       android:label="@string/titre_InfosPresentation" >
    </activity>

    <activity
       android:name="graves_de_mer.Graves_menu" 
       android:label="@string/titre_gdm" >
    </activity>

    <activity
       android:name="graves_de_mer.Presentation_gdm" 
       android:label="@string/titre_gdm" >
    </activity>

    <activity
       android:name="rouxmesnil.Rouxmesnil_menu" 
       android:label="@string/titre_rouxmesnil" >
    </activity>

     <activity
       android:name="rouxmesnil.Presentation_rouxmesnil" 
       android:label="@string/titre_rouxmesnil" >
    </activity>




</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your full manifest file to your question, so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: Did this happen after updating adt to rev 22?

Comment: Not after updating rev 22.

Comment: Is it important if my application package and my first package create while creating a project have a different name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` indicates, that something wasn't found at runtime, but were present at compiletime. Maybe some library is missing in the class path.

Comment: Thank You ! I check that :)

Comment: Thank You so much !! I didn't select the Android Private Libraries.